# JQuery Lightbox plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, lightbox2

Good day! I'd like to seek some help because the lightbox doesn't seem to work for me because I can see the image on my page but nothing is happening upon clicking it.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/lightbox.css'); ?>">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="lightbox">
        <div><img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/image1.jpg'); ?>"></div>
        <div><img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/image2.jpg'); ?>"></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js'); ?>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/lightbox.min.js'); ?>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.lightbox').lightbox();
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize lightbox with a data-lightbox attribute on the images, not with Javascript. Just remove your JS Code and replace your HTML with this one

```
<div class="lightbox">
 <div><img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/image1.jpg'); ?>" data-lightbox="image1"></div>
 <div><img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/image2.jpg'); ?>" data-lightbox="image2"></div>
</div>
```

of (if you want to have both images in the same gallery):

```
<div class="lightbox">
 <div><img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/image1.jpg'); ?>" data-lightbox="myGallery"></div>
 <div><img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/image2.jpg'); ?>" data-lightbox="myGallery"></div>
</div>
```